# Add a discoverable BLE GATT service & characterstics

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, gatt

Working on corebluetooth application i am able to discover the services as 8880 and characteristics as 8881 & 8882.After discovering those i am getting AA command from the peripheral device and in response to that i am sending 42 command back to the peripheral.UP to here is fine .In next phase to get a particular device info i am sending 70 to peripheral to receive 71 as out put but here is the problem once i send 70 peripheral is receiving that and sending back 71 but i cannot see the sended value in my console.And i have placed this quoestion to manufacturer team they have have sended the following details to add

1. add a discoverable BLE GATT service which UUID (little endian) is:
   0x44, 0x98, 0xFF, 0xD5, 0x02, 0x4F, 0x39, 0x8E, 0xFB, 0x49, 0x6A, 0xC4, 0x4A, 0x51, 0x3C, 0xE2
2. add a discoverable BLE GATT characteristic (writable, indictable and notifiable) inside the service:
   0x83, 0x46, 0xF6, 0xEB, 0x31, 0xC1, 0x85, 0x84, 0x93, 0x44, 0x57, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xB8, 0x23, 0x07
3. after receiving AA 03, send 0x42. Then their iOS app should be able to setup a logical connection for receiving data from the watch.

As per my understanding i have coded the service and characteristics as nil .My app can discover the services and characteristics provided by peripheral.But i cannot understand hoe to add the above GATT services and characteristics .Please help me with the sample code

Comment: The information from the manufacturer indicates that you need your iOS device to act as a peripheral

Comment: can u explain me clearly so i can comment back to manufacturer team.and they ask me above points  to do the following to their iOS app:

Comment: The Core Bluetooth programming guide from Apple shows how to set up a CBPeripheralManager and create CBPeripheral, add a service and characteristic

Comment: for those things i need to write code for peripheral also .?.As per my requirement my application act as a central mode and write commands to peripheral and receive response from it....

Comment: Please help me with certain instructions to follow according to my requirement........Thanks in advance

Comment: It is strange that they are telling you that your app needs to act as a peripheral, perhaps it is some form of security thing?  Here is one example I found from Google - https://github.com/KhaosT/CBPeripheralManager-Demo

Comment: can able to add the above service and characteristics when the device in peripheral mode .

Comment: Yes, those bytes they have given are just the UUID for the service and characteristic.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. You should try and then ask a question of you have a specific problem.